# book for numerical methods for solving pde

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I need to find some masters-level exercises about numerical methods for solving pde. Are there any good references?

Comment: Can you specify? There are tons of good books, many specialized on a specific method. (FEM / collocation / meshless methods etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Numerical Partial Differential Equations I and II by Thomas have become my go-to references.  They cover all the major topics (FD, FE and FV) and have lots of exercises.

Answer (score 2):

This book is very good:
Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations
Morton and Mayers